# Spring Security: Custom PreAuthorize method of same bean over an Interface unable to access bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-aop

I'm trying to do something like this (which works)

```
@Service("myService")
@Scope("session")
public class MyService {

    public boolean hasAccessOnResource(String str)
    {
        return true;
    }


    @PreAuthorize("@myService.hasAccessOnResource(#str)")
    public void execute(String str) 
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

However, when the MyService implements an Interface and i call the execute over an interface, I get an exception.

At the controller (for ref)

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myService")
    MyServiceInterface service; // <- doesn't work case
    //MyService service; <- working case

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpSession session) 
    {
        service.execute("hello");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

The service implementing an interface..

```
@Service("myService")
@Scope("session")
public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface{

    public boolean hasAccessOnResource(String str)
    {
        return true;
    }


    @PreAuthorize("@myService.hasAccessOnResource(#str)")
    @Override
    public void execute(String str) 
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 11): Method call: Method hasAccessOnResource(java.lang.String) cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52 type
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way? What is the approach i need to take if i want to PreAuthorize over this interface method?

Comment: Check if `public boolean hasAccessOnResource(String str)` is also declared in the interface

Comment: You are right! Thank you. Of course I made that mistake! This has nothing to do with spring security.